# solr: faceting using json api on enumField throws error "Expected numeric field type"

Tags: solr

When I try to facet on an enum field using the json faceting api:

```
headers = {'content-type': "application/json" }

json_query = {
    "facet": {
        "levels": {
            "type": "terms",
            "field": "type",
            "sort": "index"
        }
    }
}

response  = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(json_query), headers=headers)
```

I get the following error:

```
'error': {'metadata': ['error-class', 'org.apache.solr.common.SolrException', 
'root-error-class', 'org.apache.solr.common.SolrException'], 
'msg': 'Expected numeric field type :type{type=codeType,properties=indexed,
stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,
required,docValues,useDocValuesAsStored, required=true}', 'code': 400}
```

I found a few people having the same problem:
[this person](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Terms-faceting-and-EnumField-td4458270.html) and [this person](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Facetting-on-EnumFields-using-JSON-API-Bug-td4249278.html) but no solutions. When I use the regular parameters faceting works fine.

Comment: What's the field type of the field type?

Comment: solr.EnumFieldType

Answer (score 0):

In my case also it didnt work on enum fields, try using normal facet

```
/select?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=type
```